# Python: Swap values between columns to sort them within rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has multiple columns and I would like to sort 3 of them from min to max.

Input:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| No | MinVal | MidVal | MaxVal |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      2 |      4 |      3 |
|  2 |      5 |      6 |      8 |
|  3 |      8 |      8 |      1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| No | MinVal | MidVal | MaxVal |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      2 |      3 |      4 |
|  2 |      5 |      6 |      8 |
|  3 |      1 |      8 |      8 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

So I would like to swap values between the columns `MinVal`, `MidVal` and `MaxVal` to order them from lowest to the highest one.

I would like it to be realized without using a loop, so by using `apply()` or another function.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `sort` here

```
df=df.set_index('No')
df.values.sort(axis=1)
df
Out[212]: 
    MinVal  MidVal  MaxVal
No                        
1        2       3       4
2        5       6       8
3        1       8       8
```

Update

```
df[['MinVal','MidVal','MaxVal']]=np.sort(df[['MinVal','MidVal','MaxVal']].values,axis=1)
df
Out[215]: 
   No  MinVal  MidVal  MaxVal
0   1       2       3       4
1   2       5       6       8
2   3       1       8       8
```

Comment: `No` has to stay as column and there are more columns than these. Just did not want to make it to confusing. So I cannot sort the whole data frame.